# impoting binary file to mysql

Tags: server, mysql

i have binary files .fo and .ibd for a database and i want to import them to mysql .. 
**what i did ?**

- backup mysql folder: cp -a /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-backup
- copy database folder from old machine to /var/lib/mysql
- override ib* (ib_logfile* , ibdata ) from old database
- start mysql

**what i have ?**

- files are imported but when i try to enter any table in database iam
  getting table doesn't exist although i can see tables on phpmyadmin
  but i can't access it anyhelp please !!
  [table doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMmqC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions of ib*.

If you manually edit the directories for a database that uses InnoDB tables you need to make sure that the ib* files in the root of the MySQL datadir have correct permissions.

- Owner and group needs to be `mysql`.
- permissions need to be 644 for the ib* files.

---

If that does not work: do a `mysqldump -u {user} {database} > db.sql` of your database and reload the database from command line (`mysql -u {user} < db.sql`).

---

In case you have foreign key violations these 2 commands will fix those (and repair the tables):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: the owner of mysql directory is mysql:mysql
and i changed now permission for 3 files ib_logfile0,ib_logfile_1,ibdata1
but the problem still exists

Comment: when i enter mysqldump -u {user} {database} > db.sql
i get : **mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'carbon_db.2zr0q5_commentmeta' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
**